# Plotting point based on angle and distance from another given point in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I am using QGIS 2.18.10.

If I have a given point with an easting and a northing, and know its distance and angle from a transit which took the initial point, how do I plot the location of the transit if I don't already have its easting and northing?

As a secondary question; the transit took a further 900 points (an archaeological scatter which I'm plotting). Once I have the location of the transit, how would I calculate and plot those other points as a batch, based on their distances and angles from the transit, instead of inputting them individually?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 3):

Look into the "Azimuth and Distance" plugin. There is a usage example here: https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-azimuth-distance-plugin

That should do exactly what you need, and it is even possible to import a file to automatically treat  your 900 points.

Comment: Hello Leyan, thank you for that answer. I see that plugin now. I presume it's completely different, with a different set of functions, than the Azimuth and Distance calculator?